# Changing the model without redirecting to the update page

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

In my controller there's the update method, I want it like this, If I click the update button the $model->status = ('Done'); without redirecting it to the update page.

What I have tried so far, the page refreshes but the $model->status doesn't change into 'Done'

```
 public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
       return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        $model->status = ('Done');
        $model->time_end = date('y-m-d h-i-s');
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please, can you improve the question, so people can find it.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I've already found the solution:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $model->status = ('Done');
    $model->time_end = date('y-m-d h-i-s');

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
       return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, can you elaborate on the answer you are posting, so it helps others.